# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, database, jdbc, connection, classpath

I've installed MaxDB in my local machine and I'm trying to make a connection to it using Java.

And I'm getting this error when running :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sap.dbtech.jdbc.DriverSapDB

```
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)

at sap.maxdb.Hello.main(Hello.java:15)
```

This is the code I'm using :

```
package sap.maxdb;

import java.sql.*;

public class Hello
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
String username = "DBM";
String password = "azerty";
String dbname = "SAPDB";

Class.forName ("com.sap.dbtech.jdbc.DriverSapDB");
String url = "jdbc:sapdb://" + dbname;

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection (url, username, password);
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement ();
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM HOTEL.CUSTOMER");
resultSet.next ();
String hello = resultSet.getString (1);
System.out.println (hello);

resultSet.close ();
stmt.close();
connection.close ();
}
}
```

I did like they said in their [website](http://maxdb.sap.com/doc/7_7/37/5f6b6e966242aead8025bdc5296489/content.htm) :

> set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Program
>   Files\sdb\programs\runtime\jar\sapdbc.jar

But I get always the same error.

I know that I'm missing something but can't find it °!°

Waiting for your help.

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: try `set CLASSPATH="%CLASSPATH%;C:\Program Files\sdb\programs\runtime\jar\sapdbc.jar"`

Comment: You must quote your classpath if it contains a space.

Comment: I tried with and without quotes and it's not working yet.

Comment: How are you running this? From an IDE, from the command line, from a script? A description of what you are doing, or better yet, the actual command/script you are running will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does "install" mean? Basically, the db server must be installed and running.

Step two is to add the driver (which you can find under `C:\Program Files\sdb\programs\runtime\jar\sapdbc.jar`, assuming this applies to your installation too) to the build path of your project. If the driver class cannot be found, it'll raise a `ClassNotFoundException` as you experienced.

You don't mention which IDE you are using, but try to set your project buildpath from the context menu.

Comment: Then right click on the project, `Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries tab -> Add External JARs`. Select the sapdbc.jar from the file browser and click OK. Build path problems should be resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following code to make sure that your application picks up the CLASSPATH that you specified:

```
    Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
        System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName, env.get(envName));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the driver's jar file to the 'lib' folder of the server. Then restart the server.